# JavaFX custom controls from code

Tags: view, javafx-2, javafx, controls, custom-controls

Can you point me out good documentation/practices for developing **custom** controls?
I checked the [official doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm), but it's not enough for me.

I would like to display a `Label` or a `TextField` and wrap it with a `Path` object to create a border.

Please find here a sample of what I want to create :
[image]

From top to bottom, left to right :

- Label, Textfield,
- Label, Passwordfield (textfield with blur effect)
- Label selectable (and clickable), and CheckBox with Label at the right.

(when textfield, passwordfield or checkbox are selected, the color is CYAN too)

I achieved to create that controls in a custom class extending Region, displaying a Text and Paths/Lines.
And subclasses specialize by adding textfield/checkbox items in it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523341/adding-a-tilepane-instantiated-in-java-files-to-fxml/19705340#19705340 
scene bilder can help you

Comment: Ok, but I found the Control/Skin/Behaviour pattern for designing a custom control, anyone knows a good tutorial about it?

Comment: scene builder are design for make reliable and effective way to design fxml...its nice approch

Comment: Ok, but I don't want particularly use fxml in my application. I want to design a new control with code.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts_b2mBix3U
This presentation is quite good :)

Comment: @PacDroid: Can you provide a sketch of how your custom control should look like? Adding custom borders can be achieved with [css styling](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html), too.

Comment: I've added it, I don't know if it's possible to do in CSS, but it would be great.